Angular component rendered two times
I create an Angular 18 client with a spring-boot backend and a Keycloak-angular 16.0.1 auth middleware. The problem is I get the content of app.component.html rendered 2x after I logged in and open the root url. On page /doctor or /home everiting fine, but on root I get two menubar.

The content of this html is:
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

The app-routing.module.ts is this:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { KeycloakGuard } from './auth/keycloak.guard';
import {DoctorComponent} from './doctor/doctor.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent, canActivate: [KeycloakGuard] },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'doctors', component: DoctorComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

The DOM is normally in Doctor view:

The project is on github: https://github.com/pzoli/forras-ng-module
Please help me find solution. Thanks for suggestions.

Hi. Its like you render the navbar component in one of the children components
Like Home. If the HTML is AppComponent, try remove the navbar tag

Just the AppComponent must have only the router outlet

I updated the image of error (added DOM tree view). I need  in a central place to show navigation bar in every page. So I don''t want put it in home component because doctor page need it, too. Before I put keycloak-angular component in my code everithing is fine.

Your current routing definition calls for the router-outlet in AppComponent to render AppComponent...
Try changing to:

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [KeycloakGuard]},
  { path: 'doctors', component: DoctorComponent },
];


